# Retrieve content from another div and apply in new div

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, html

I have an application that's dynamically creates div boxes and through AJAX loads images that are placed inside the boxes.

If a box already exists I don't want to load the images (through AJAX) again. Instead the content (ie. the images) should be grabbed from the first box and applied in the new one.

By that reason I want to do something like this:
"If one box exists, retrieve the content from that box and apply it in the new box."

Below is a piece of code that shows what I want. What I need to know is how to find out if a box exists (line 1) and how to apply the content in the new box (line 3).

```
1. if (box exist...?) {
2.    var content = $('.boxContent').html();
3.    $('.boxContent') ?
4. }
5.
6. else {
7. 
8. // retrieve the images through AJAX and place in the box...
9.
10. }
```

Comment: your question is too vague. please specify exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.boxContent').is('*')) { //it exists
    var content = $('.boxContent').html(); 
    var newBox = $('<div id="new-box"></div>');
    newBox.html(content);
}
```

Alternatively, you can clone:

```
if ($('.boxContent').is('*')) { //it exists
    var newBox = $('.boxContent').clone(); 
    // newBox is an EXACT copy of the .boxContent
}
```

I would recommend using an ID instead of a class selector in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can tell if something exists in the DOM by simply selecting it and loooking at the length of the collection:

```
var boxes = $('.boxContent')
if (boxes.length) {
  var content = boxes[0].html();
} else {
  // AJAX
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to check if some element is available in jQuery is:

```
if($('element').length != 0){//element exists
        `$('newElement').html($('element').html());`
}
else{
     //ajax stuff
}
```